# How to create temp channel join a discord channel?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot to create temp channel.
You join a main channel and it creates a channel with your name then you're switch inside.

I just need to know how to move the user who joined the main channel can be moved in the channel which was created.

I got this so far :

```
export const joinToCreate: Function = async (oldState: any, newState: any): Promise<void> => {
  if (newState.channel.id === "861987613598810122") {
    const joinedUsername = newState.member.user.username;
    const newChannel = await newState.guild.channels.create(`${joinedUsername}'s mix`, {
      type: "voice",
      parent: newState.channel.parent,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `newChannel` is a promise, which you awaited. Now you can easily move the member to the channel with [VoiceState.setChannel()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel). Here is how you can implement it

```js
//newChannel declaration
newState.setChannel(newChannel);
```

If this is not what you wanted, I’m sorry but your question was pretty unclear

Comment: Well my question was unclear but your answer was pretty clear, and that's exactly what i needed. Thx